# Java using relative path instead of absolute path

Tags: java, relative-path, readfile

I am reading in a file in Java and when I use the absolute path it works fine.

```
File myObj = new File("/Users/aaronmk2/Downloads/demo2/SystemDependencies/src/sample_input.txt");
```

However, when I try to use the relative path I get a No such file or directory error

```
File myObj = new File("../sample_input.txt");
```

When I use my terminal and use `nano ../sample_input.txt` it opens up the file.

What do I need to add to get the relative path to work?

Comment: What is the `cwd` and classpath during runtime? How are you executing the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does relative paths just fine. Clearly, then, the 'current working directory' for your java process is not the same as the cwd when you're invoking `nano`.

You can check the CWD in java. Either way will work:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

or:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

You should find that it is different. The 'cwd' for a java process is the cwd that it was set to by whatever started java. If you're invoking java from the command line, it'll be the directory you're in as you do so. If you are double clicking a jar, it'll be the directory the jar is in. If you're making a windows shortcut, it's the directory listed in the shortcut. Example:

```
cd /foo/bar
java -jar /bar/baz/hello.jar
```

In the above example, the cwd is `/foo/bar`. Not `/bar/baz`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add src/ before the file name

Comment: Note that this means it won't work when you build your code (there is no 'src' after building, obviously). If this is read-only data, the file should be loaded with ClassYouAreIn.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt"), putting 'file.txt' in the same place as ClassYoUAreIn.class. If you're using maven, put the file in src/resources just like how your src files are in src/java. If using another build system, look up how to get that done. This means the data will also be read when in the jar. If it's an editable file, it shuld not be with the code, it should be in ~ for example.